# Is there an advantage to localization if only one language?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, localization

If you are creating text for only one language, is there any advantage to localizing (resx files) the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just one language it might still be nice to have all of the text in one place so you can easily adjust the text and reuse the text.

But if it is your goal to edit and reuse a proper content management system might be a better fit.

Otherwise the only upside is being prepared to go multi-language very quickly. You never know when you'll need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that this requirement won't change, there is no advantage. In fact, there is the disadvantage of higher complexity.

You might anticipate that the requirement for localization might come, but most people would throw you a [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) in the face.